# What is the equivalent of _emit on Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

I'm trying to port some assembly code written in Visual Studio into GNU inline assembly on Linux. The original code uses [_emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b80826t.aspx) which MSDN describes as a pseudo instruction and explains as:

> The _emit pseudoinstruction is similar to the DB directive of MASM. You use _emit to define a single immediate byte at the current location in the current text segment. However, _emit can define only one byte at a time, and it can only define bytes in the text segment. It uses the same syntax as the INT instruction.

How can I do the same thing on Linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To emit byte 0x12 (for example), do:

```
asm __volatile__ (".byte 0x12");
```

Although, you might get surprising results with optimizations enabled.

Comment: With `__volatile__` (or simply `volatile` on modern compilers) you shouldn't have any issue even with optimizations enabled. The compiler must emit the byte at the location indicated (of course, the surrounding code might be heavy optimized...).